# Modify document root for nginx proxy under plesk

Tags: nginx, plesk, document-root

I use Plesk with nginx as proxy, which is working good.
I installed laravel php framework on a subdomain. the framework provides a direcotry "public" for public files, so I changed document_root with a custom vhost.conf file this way:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/laravel.example.com/public"
```

Now apache is aware of this, PHP files working without any problems, but not the static files which are handeled via nginx, I get 404 not found because I must also reconfig the document_root for nginx.

If I copy the static files, like css or js on the same dir-level as public it works, but the static files should be in "public".

how to reconfig the document root for this nginx vhost now? I tried to add

```
root /var/www/vhosts/example.com/laravel.example.com/public;
```

into the server { ... and "then location /" directive ...

to a custom nginx.conf file in the "conf" directroy of plesk for this vhost but dont work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For **Plesk 12.0 and above** there UI controls to specify domain's additional nginx/apache directives in "Web Server Settings":

[image: plesk customize nginx config]

For **Plesk 11.5** you can add custom directive:

1. mkdir /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/custom/domain
2. cp /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/default/domain/nginxDomainVirtualHost.php
   /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/custom/domain/
3. add in /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/custom/domain/nginxDomainVirtualHost.php:

   ```
   <?php if (file_exists($VAR->domain->physicalHosting->vhostDir . '/conf/nginx.conf')): ?>
       include <?php echo $VAR->domain->physicalHosting->vhostDir;?>/conf/nginx.conf;
   <?php endif ?>
   ```
4. /usr/local/psa/admin/bin/httpdmng --reconfigure-all # to apply new configuration for all domains

As result, if domain has **conf/nginx.conf** - it will be included into virtual host config.

Comment: worked great, thx and sorry for late comeback ... after restarting nginx i have this warnings:

 nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "laravel.example.com" on 118.xxx.104.xxx:80, ignored ... but i works now

Comment: looks like there is duplication of ServerName directive in conf/nginx.conf. I think you can play around with removing duplicate directives.